# How to set footer stay at bottom of page by using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

I'm trying to set the footer to the bottom by using angular.

I created a footer component, and trying to use it in app.component.html as:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id='page'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
```

and set the app.component.scss like this:

```
    #container{
        min-height:100%; 
        height: auto !important;
        position: relative;
    }
    #page{
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
    }
    app-footer{
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height: 2.5rem;
        clear: both;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: darkgray;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
```

the footer works well at the page bottom when the text in router-outlet(main/other component) is shorter than the view page(100%), but if I have longer text than the view page, the footer is still at the 100vh position, does not goes down to the bottom.
I checked some solution and demos, seems like the traditional css/html solution works well, but when I tried the same thought with using angular8, it has some problem. Is that means the main component height is set to smaller than 100% by angular, not the exact height as their should be?

Comment: Do you mean you want the footer to always stay at the bottom of the page?

Comment: yes, just like all web pages.

Comment: Check out my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313118/8967115

Answer (score 2):

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#page {
    flex: 1;
}
```

no need to make app-footer position absolute