# How to fix the footer in 4k resolution?

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, footer

When i put in 4k resolution, the footer rises and a blank space appears below it.

I've tried to put the html height 100%, but it doesn't work it.

[image: ![Like this]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ImME.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the height of the main content such that footer is always at the bottom. Something like:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header,
footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid">
  <div class="header bg-warning"></div>
  <div class="main bg-success"></div>
  <footer class="bg-danger"></footer>
</div>
```

OR use `flex`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a good approach... only problem is that you need to specifically set the footer's height to a static value. In fact, that's the issue with CSS solutions for this, and it's why I chose to go with JS.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following CSS to your footer class

```
.footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: A complete solution in terms of a CSS approach is way more complex than that @chaitanya. That code just creates an overlapping of the footer (on top of the other elemtns of the page) when the window size is smaller than the page content. I, myself, prefer the JS approach.

Comment: Go with the @d.b solution. Actually I thought of giving the same approach, having fixed header and footer height and subtracting the sum of header of footer heights from 100vh which will be height of main content.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different solutions for that in SO, most of them using CSS, however, the approach I've found to be the best solution is to use JavaScript to keep the footer at the bottom of the page when the window resizes. Here's a code sample using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function adjustFooter() {
        var footer = $("footer");

        if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
            footer.css("position", "inherit");
        } else {
            footer.css({"position": "absolute", "bottom": "0"});
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustFooter();
    });

    adjustFooter();

});
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2019 <strong>SomeBrand</strong> - All rights reserved</p>
</footer>
```